# SQL won't execute after fopen fwrite large file

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite, fclose

I'm using fopen, fwrite and fclose to rewrite a file. When I am re-writing a large file of 50mb the file rewrites successfully but the sql statement after fclose does not execute and neither does the echo at the bottom. The sql does execute for files of 20mb

Any ideas?

```
set_time_limit(10000);

if (!file_exists($filename)) {
echo "file missing";
}
else{   
$fr = fopen($filename, "r"); 
$file = "";
$file = fgets($fr, 4096);
while(!feof($fr)){ 

//read from file

    $file =str_replace("\r","",$file);
    $file =str_replace("\n","",$file);
    $file =str_replace("~","",$file);

//write to file
    $fw = fopen($tempfile, "a") or die("Couldn't create new file"); 
    fwrite($fw, $file); 
    $file = fgets($fr, 4096); 
     } 
fclose($fw);
fclose($fr); 

//set status to 5
$update_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("Update bs_uploads set UploadStatus=5 where 
UploadNewFilename=?");
$update_stmt->bind_param("s", $original_filename);
$update_stmt->execute();

 echo "finished";   

}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not taking longer than 10 seconds to run on big files? You have `set_time_limit(10000);`  Have you tried increasing that?

Comment: time limit is 10000 seconds, the file completely rewrites no matter what size it is, just the sql after does not

Comment: Try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` as the top 2 lines of your code, see if anything is reported.

Comment: thanks Nigel that helped

Answer (score 0):

It seems to loose the mysqli connection when the script runs for a long time.
I solved this by moving my connection statement which I had at the top of the page to just above my sql update statements.

```
fclose($fw);
fclose($fr); 

include("connect_mysqli.inc.php");

//set status to 5
$update_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("Update bs_uploads set UploadStatus=5 where 
UploadNewFilename=?");
$update_stmt->bind_param("s", $original_filename);
$update_stmt->execute();

echo "finished";   

}
```